# Flex/Accordion: Conditionally hide a child

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do I hide a child in a accordion? Using visible doesn't seem to work and enabled isn't what I'm after.

```
<mx:Accordion>
<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" label="Foo" id="viewOverview" visible="false">
...
</mx:VBox>
...
</mx:Accordion>
```

Comment: Have you tried includeInLayout=false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can't hide it. Strange that the visible property doesn't work... Anyway, I would control the children through code and remove and insert them as needed by the app. Hiding:

```
function hideFoo():void {
    this.theAccordion.removeChild(this.vboxFoo);
}
```

You'll probably want to keep a reference to the "hidden" child so that you can add it later again.

Comment: You can easily automate this method by using states.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, just some curious things I found out while trying to find another solution to this problem:

Accordion headers have a visible property and a setActualSize method. The latter takes a height and width, and setting each to zero...

acc.getHeaderAt(0).setActualSize(0,0);

...accomplishes the same thing as setting visible = false, that is it hides the contents of the header, but does not remove its area from the accordion. I was hoping to trick the accordion into hiding the child, but no such luck...nonetheless, it might be a path to continue to try. If I get more time I will continue to explore but I'm out of bandwidth at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a descendant of accordion with methods like showHeader, hideHeader, isHeaderHidden that contains hash table to keep track of hidden elements similar to the one below:

```
public class AccordionHideHeader extends Accordion
    {
        private var _hiddenHeader:Dictionary=new Dictionary();

        public function AccordionHideHeader()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function hideHeader(header:DisplayObject):void
        {
            if (contains(header))
            {
                _hiddenHeader[header]=getChildIndex(header);
                removeChild(header);
            }


        }

        public function showHeader(header:DisplayObject):void
        {
            if (!contains(header))
            {
                addChildAt(header, _hiddenHeader[header]);
                delete _hiddenHeader[header]
            }
        }

        public function isHeaderHidden(header:DisplayObject):Boolean
    {                       
        for (var key:Object in _hiddenHeader)
        {
            if (key==header)
                return true;                
        }

        return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm not agree with removing child, because you will having problem when adding it back to its position in exact order.

Example: If you have 5 page in accordion, you remove child 1 and 3, now in any condition you want number 3 back to acordion how do you put it back? because the index is not 3 anymore (rember that 1 is removed too).

I found a good solution [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/30/preventing-users-from-clicking-on-an-accordion-containers-header-in-flex/). In short you make your own acordion with enalbe and disable ability where enable and disable define on the child container.

here i paste the acordion code:

```
/**
 * http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/30/preventing-users-from-clicking-on-an-accordion-containers-header-in-flex/
 */
package comps {
    import mx.containers.accordionClasses.AccordionHeader;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    public class MyAccHeader extends AccordionHeader {
        public function MyAccHeader() {
            super();
            addEventListener(FlexEvent.INITIALIZE, accordionHeader_initialize);
        }

        private function accordionHeader_initialize(evt:FlexEvent):void {
            enabled = data.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe my answer not relevant anymore for you, but i hope can help someone else who face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can override Accordion logic and user includeInLayout property to control visibility of children.

This will work if you set all children in MXML.

```
import flash.events.Event;

import mx.containers.Accordion;
import mx.core.UIComponent;

public class DynamicAccordion extends Accordion
{
public function DynamicAccordion()
{
}

private var allChildern:Array;

override protected function childrenCreated():void
{
    allChildern = new Array();
    for (var i:int = numChildren - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        var child:UIComponent = getChildAt(i) as UIComponent;
        if (child)
        {
            child.addEventListener("includeInLayoutChanged",  childIncludeLayoutChangedHandler);
            if (!child.includeInLayout)
            {
                removeChild(child);
            }
            allChildern.push(child);
        }
    }
    allChildern = allChildern.reverse();

    super.childrenCreated();
}

private function childIncludeLayoutChangedHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var child:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;
    if (child.includeInLayout)
    {
        var index:int = allChildern.indexOf(child);
        addChildAt(child, index);
    }
    else
    {
        removeChild(child);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to actually remove the accordion child itself (e.g. using the State removeChild() mechanism). If you need to preserve the object itself, just keep a reference to it in a global variable.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Accordion controls always have 1 child open.  By opening another child, the current one will close.

If you want to have more than 1 child open at a time or have all children closed, you can use the VStack component available at: http://weblogs.macromedia.com/pent/archives/2007/04/the_stack_compo.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        private function hideFn():void
        {
            acc.removeChildAt(0);                   
        }

        private function showFn():void
        {
            acc.addChildAt(helloBox  , 0);              
        } 

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:VBox>
<mx:Accordion id="acc" width="200" height="200">    

    <mx:VBox id="helloBox" label="Test">

        <mx:Label text="hello"/>

    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox label="Test2">

        <mx:Label text="hello again"/>

    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Accordion>

<mx:Button label="hide" click="hideFn()"/>
<mx:Button label="show" click="showFn()"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
accrod.getHeaderAt(0).enabled=false;
accrod.getHeaderAt(0).visible=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution :

http://weflex.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/flex-accordion-hideshow-headers/

I copied and modified the code of the Accordion, so if a child has its "includeInLayout" property to false, it won't be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution, how to collapse the accordion on click of header.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;

        private var isAccordionClosed:Boolean;

        private function myAccordion_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.currentTarget.label);
            var selIdx:int = myAccordion.selectedIndex;

            isAccordionClosed = (isAccordionClosed) ? false : true; 
            if (isAccordionClosed)
            {
                collapseAccordion(selIdx, !isAccordionClosed);
            }
            else
            {
                collapseAccordion(selIdx, !isAccordionClosed);
            }
        }

        private function collapseAccordion(idx:int, showHide:Boolean):void
        {
            switch(idx)
            {
                case 0:
                    vb1.scaleX = vb1.scaleY = int(showHide); 
                    break;

                case 1:
                    vb2.scaleX = vb2.scaleY = int(showHide);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    vb3.scaleX = vb3.scaleY = int(showHide);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    vb4.scaleX = vb4.scaleY = int(showHide); 
                    break;

                case 4:
                    vb5.scaleX = vb5.scaleY = int(showHide);
                    break;
            }
        }


        private function myAccordion_changeHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
        {
            isAccordionClosed = true;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Accordion id="myAccordion" x="200" y="200" click="myAccordion_clickHandler(event)" resizeToContent="true" 
              width="399" verticalGap="0" change="myAccordion_changeHandler(event)">
    <mx:VBox id="vb1" label="Chapter 1">
        <mx:Label text="Accordion 1"  width="397" textAlign="center" height="38"/>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox id="vb2" label="Chapter 2">
        <mx:Label text="Accordion 2" width="397" textAlign="center" height="43"/>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox id="vb3" label="Chapter 3">
        <mx:Label text="Accordion 3" width="397" textAlign="center" height="43"/>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox id="vb4" label="Chapter 4">
        <mx:Label text="Accordion 4" width="397" textAlign="center" height="43"/>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox id="vb5" label="Chapter 5">
        <mx:Label text="Accordion 5" width="397" textAlign="center" height="43"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Comment: This is no answer to the question. The question is about making a component inside an accordion invisible by setting the `visible` or `includeinlayout` property on the child component.